# grpcurl to Google Cloud Run Java grpc server always returns context deadline exceeded

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-run

I have copied a simple grpc java service from this repo.

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples/example-hostname

I have deployed this service to Google cloud run. I am trying to verify the service is setup correctly. Any grpcurl request sent to the service returns.

Failed to dial target host "my-hobby-service-vxkahalqoq-an.a.run.app:8080": context deadline exceeded

Comment: Can you connect at all? For example using telnet or netcat?

Comment: Total noob here, never used either of those tools. When I hit the url in the browser I get

Content-Type is missing from the request

Comment: It looks like you're trying to connect to port 8080. Did you try port 443 (the standard https port)?

Comment: Does the app run [locally](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local), start and it is [listening](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#port) on the declared port? Please, take a look at [error reporting](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/error-reporting) and share any other one related error.

Comment: Note: I was able to successfully ping my service using grpcurl

grpcurl my-hobby-service-vxkahalqoq-an.a.run.app:8080 list
---->
Failed to dial target host "my-hobby-service-vxkahalqoq-an.a.run.app:8080": context deadline exceeded


grpcurl my-hobby-service-vxkahalqoq-an.a.run.app:443 list
----->
grpc.health.v1.Health
grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection
helloworld.Greeter

So apparently the issue was I was trying to ping port 8080 and Google cloud was actually exposing on port 443.